# AngularJS and line breaks

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having some issues once again. There's a very simple form:

```
<form ng-submit="funcion_modelo_adherir_cadena()">
<textarea ng-model="nuevo_modelo.scan_addresses" name="nuevo_modelo.scan_addresses" value="" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="deliver_info" value="deliver information"/>
```

That, as you can see, uses the `function funcion_modelo_adherir_cadena()` once it's submited.

The function `funcion_modelo_adherir_cadena()` doesn't do anything else than collecting the information inside the form and sending it to a PHP controller:

```
$scope.funcion_modelo_adherir_cadena = function() {
    //armamos la cadena
    $scope.cadena_creacion_modelo = "?ac=massive_add";

    //adherimos cada uno de los campos
    angular.forEach($scope.nuevo_modelo, function(value, key) {
        $scope.cadena_creacion_modelo += ("&"+key +"="+ value);
    });

    var address = "../asyn/mapas_add.php" + $scope.cadena_creacion_modelo

    //demandamos la información
    var pedido = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: address
    })

    //si las cosas salen bien
    .success(function(data, status) {

        //refrescamos la información
        $scope.funcion_modelo_visualizacion_masiva();

        //escondemos información
        $scope.visualizar_menu_adhesion = '';
    });
}
```

The code above works without any problem, sending the information into the PHP controller waiting for it.

**There's only 1 problem here:**

Any line break on the textarea is completely ignored. No `/r`, no `/r/n`, no `<br>`, no `%0A`. the information goes all together as far as I can see, even without spaces in the middle.

Anyone has any idea how I can fix this or even why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show the code where you're setting new value for `nuevo_modelo.scan_addresses`?

Answer (score 0):

Textarea will not take any formatters. So please use any rich text editors. Here is an angular directive for Tinymce rich text editor.

**[Tinymce](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce)**

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's enough to wrap your textarea in a `pre` tag.

`<pre><textarea ...></textarea></pre>`